# Why is nothing working right here?

Tags: permissions

I used the Crouton method via Ray Waldo's website to get the Linux OS.

I have it and at first it looked ok but there are problems already. When I switched back, Steam won't launch, I have no way of ending the application as there is no 'task manager' as far as I know like a windows computer to see if restarting it would work [so where is the task manager?]

Second, the Synaptic Package Manager wont run. No idea what's up with that.

Finally why does it keep asking for administrative access passwords? My little brother is supposed to be using this computer freely without problems so I want it to stop giving the 'no access' screens whenever I put in a flash drive, and the password requests for about everything else. He is mentally differently abled and won't understand how to work around the complicated measures for him [basically it should be able to know he is the only admin and stop showing those screens.]

As for what the computer has, take a look at this [www.walmart.com](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Acer-Granite-Gray-11.6-C720-2827-Chromebook-PC-with-Intel-Celeron-2955U-Processor-2GB-Memory-16GB-SSD-and-Chrome-OS/34334436)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a task manager. Search for `System Monitor` in Dash. It allows you to easily kill tasks, view resource usage per process, total RAM & CPU usage etc.

Ubuntu will only ask for a password when you want to change something on the PC, like remove or install software, partitioning your hard drive, adding or removing users etc. Normal tasks won't ask for a password. You can't disable it as it's how Ubuntu (and other Linux based operating systems) work.

To solve your problem with crashing packages we'll need more info. Update your question with some logs or tell us what you do and what happens.

Comment: There is no crash, I just click the Synaptic package manager and nothing comes up. Not one error message. As for System Monitor I still don't see it. I have looked in every section of the startmenu and nothing says System Monitor